# Closed form of a summable collection

Tags: summation, partial-fractions

Let$\:(m,n,k)\underset{k\:\text{fixed}}{\in}\mathbf{N^3}\begin{equation}
  \:\:\land a_{m,n}=\begin{cases}
    \left( m^{-k}-n^{-k}\right)^{-1} \ &, m\neq n\\
    0 &, m=n.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
$

Is $\{a_{m,n}\}_{_{\large (m,n)\in\mathbf N^2}}\:\:$a summable collection?

First thought is obviously to look for $$\sum_{m\ge 0}\sum_{n\ge 0}a_{m,n}=\sum_{m\ge 0}\sum_{n\ge 0}\left({A\over{m-n}}+{B\over{\sum_{_{\large j=0}}^{k-1}}m^j\:n^{k-j-1}}\right),$$ where $A,B\:$are to be found, which is not a piece of cake to yield a fresh closed form.

Although, if we let the permutation $a_{m,n}\mapsto \ a_{n,m}$

$$\large\:\sigma\normalsize=\sum_{m\ge 0}\sum_{n\ge 0}a_{m,n}=\sum_{n\ge 0}\sum_{m\ge 0}a_{n,m}\underset{_{k\:\text{even}}}{=}-\sum_{n\ge 0}\sum_{m\ge 0}a_{m,n}=-\large \sigma$$

So$\:\{a_{m,n}\}_{_{\large (m,n)\in\mathbf N^2}}\:\:$is not a summable collection by $\text{Fubini Theorem}.$

Note: $$a_{m,n}:=a_{m,n}(k)\implies a_{m,n}(2)={1\over{2m}}\left({1\over{n-m}}-{1\over{n+m}}\right),m\ne n$$

Now, two things : Trick to yield a closed form of $\sigma$; see wether or not the collection is summable for even $k$ exponents.

Any input is appreciated.

Cheers